# How to make MongoDb (local database) also be accessible via internet the same time

Tags: database, mongodb, remote-access

my plan of setup is to make the local database accessible to the local computers because of heavy manipulation of data and it needs a fast response, but at the same time, I wanted to access it via internet when I'm away from the local network. is this possible?

Currently Using MERN stack

**I tried MLAB but the response of data is pretty slow**

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you're going down a dangerous path. MongoDB comes with local authentication and a standard 27017 port. To make it available online you need to

1. remove authentication (which is not on by default)
2. change or remove the bindIp option
3. ensure the port is not blocked by firewall

This can be done in the config file. 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/

However, what you really want to do, probably to create routes within express so that users can communicate with your mongo is a structured and safe manner. More information in this here http://mean.io/2017/10/31/getting-started-mean-io/

Comment: Thank you sir will look into it.